# In query results, preven comma after last number in series

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
declare @id varchar(500);
set @id=''

select @id =@id+( convert(varchar,business_event_id) +',') 
    from bem.business_event_header substring 
print @id
```

I don't want comma after the last number.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(500);

SET @id = '';

SELECT @id = @id+(CONVERT( VARCHAR, business_event_id)+',')
FROM   bem.business_event_header substring;

SELECT @id = SUBSTRING(@id, 1, CHAR_LENGTH
      (@id)-1);

PRINT @id;
```